# How to parse a csv file encoded in GB18030 with Apache Commons CSV

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-csv

I have a csv file encoded with GB18030, and I want to use *apache commons CSV* to parse the file and get the chinese characters inside the file.

How to do this? as I got some wired character using default configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out not a *Apache Commons CSV* package problem. It's java IO reader problem.

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), Charset.forName("GB18030"));
```

Using specified *charset* when read file using java would help.